# Beginner question - VB - change a button based on an integer

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a large number of buttons on it, each named btn1 through btn25. I have another button that is generating a random number and saving it to an integer variable intDrawn.

I'd like to know if there's a simple way to alter a particular button based on the result in intDrawn; if intDrawn = 5, then I want to change the font in btn5, for example.

Is there a way to alter a control programmatically like this? I'm using Visual Basic Express 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be better to use a control array.  Give your buttons the same name and then use the integer result to change the font for that particular control number in the array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxt4418a%28VS.80%29.aspx - VB6
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28VS.71%29.aspx - VB.Net

Comment: Thanks for the links! I thought it would involve something like an array of controls but didn't know if there was a way around it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a control array of buttons, and then use the index into this array to alter a particular button.

[Control Arrays](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-control-array-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a "stupid" way to do this. Add an invisible textbox and after getting your random number you can just text1.text = "btn" + randomnumber, and then change the color or whatever you wish using text1.text.

Comment: I can get the the text for textbox1 to equal the name of the button control, but how can I manipulate the button itself given the name of the control as a string?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, for example if you want to change the caption of the button it should be buttonname.caption = "Caption abc"

Answer (score 0):

Control Array is the better choice, but you could also achieve it with reflection.